# Purpose of header files in cpp

Tags: c++, header-files

Why is there a need to include the header file of a class into the implementation file of the same class??
Does it serve a purpose??

Since i thought it is needed only where we need to use that class.

Comment: Short answer: Because C. Because compilers.

Comment: Header file shall have your class signature while your cpp file will have the implementation details

Comment: Have you tried without? Did it work?

Comment: Nope it didnt work

Comment: The marked duplicate doesn't really answer the question this one seems to be asking.  This question seems to specifically be interested in why the header with a class's definition needs to be included in the translation unit(s) defining that class's members.

Comment: Exactly!! thats what i wanted to ask

Comment: @MilesBudnek: I've added another dupe to cover that. The first covers the title question.

Comment: Yup ,that does answer it.